# Why is there an inflection point at the critical isotherm on a PV diagram?

Tags: thermodynamics, phase-diagram

I am starting to learn thermodynamics to get a better understanding of the equations of state for CO$_2$. According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_point_(thermodynamics)) there is an inflection point at the critical point for a critical isotherm on a $PV$ diagram:
$$
\left( \frac{\partial p}{\partial V} \right)_T = 0\\
\left( \frac{\partial^2 p}{\partial V^2} \right)_T = 0
$$

If I reduce the volume at a critical point at constant temperature, why doesn't the pressure increase? To me it seem logical that the pressure should always increase when I reduce the volume.

Comment: It's because the ideal gas model doesn't work in all cases. It's mostly a good approximation but in some circumstances (like this one, or when you're trying to liquidify a real gas) some other models are used, for instance the [Van der Waals gas model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_equation). If you look at the PV characteristic below, you can see where the inflection point arises.

Comment: The ideal gas law works on "ideal" gases, which do not condense.  For CO2 near its critical point, a decrease in volume causes some of the gas to condense into liquid, and this change partially or totally offsets the expected pressure increase.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are right when substance is in pure state. When there is a phase change, e.g. from vapor to liquid, the temperature and pressure can be held constant but the volume decreases, i.e. from vapor to liquid.